# PyMdown Snippets extension not working

Tags: python, markdown

I have I markdown file named "file.md" with the following content:

```
#hello world
```

Than I am trying to run the code:

```
echo '--8<-- "file.md"' | /usr/bin/python3 -m markdown -q -o html5 --noisy -x pymdownx.snippets
```

Resulting in this:

```
<p>--8&lt;-- "file.md"</p>
```

When it should echo:

```
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

The project page is at https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/snippets/

I also tried the syntax:

```
--8<-- 
filename.md
filename2.md
--8<--
```

But with similar results.

Any light?

---

Edit: I was able to make it work like this:

Worked at the same directory:

```
rgr@atpc: ls
agenda.md  file.md  home  in  teste
rgr@atpc: cat file.md 
#hello world
rgr@atpc: echo '--8<-- "file.md"' | /usr/bin/python3 -m  markdown -q -o html5 --noisy -x pymdownx.snippets
Successfuly imported extension module "pymdownx.snippets".
Successfully loaded extension "pymdownx.snippets.SnippetExtension".
<h1>hello world</h1>rgr@atpc:
```

Comment: Um what is with '--8<-- ? Also why echo something, when I am guessing you are trying to pipe the file to the python program. Just do this: `file.md > /usr/bin/python3 -m markdown -q -o html5 --noisy -x pymdownx.snippets`

Comment: PyMdown Snippets is an extension for making includes in Markdown text. The notation: https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/snippets/#snippets-notation

Comment: Sorry about the stupid assumption on my part.  But I was able to replicate your problem and also have it working.  The only way I get that issue is if I do the following: `echo '--8<--"file.md"' | python -m markdown -q -o html5 --noisy -x pymdownx.snippets` as you can see with no space with the --8<-- and filestring. If I have space it works.  Now I am not saying that is your issue, but I suspect it has to do with some type of whitespace handling.

Comment: No, it still did not work for me. What do you get when you fire `python --version` ?

Comment: Python 3.5.3
Also is this echo being executed from a script or are you pasting this into command line?

Comment: My default Python is 2.7. I need to specify the python3 path. I was able to make it work. I updated my question.